# private messaging system in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a messaging system in my rails app. I already have it working properly for sending messages between 2 users(sender and recipient). This setup is fine but how can I make a new conversation for each room so the uniqueness checking will be only between an user and a room or viceversa?? Each user is only allowed to send message to a room from the room show page. So room_id can be fetched there. A single user can have many listings which makes it complicated for me.So am confused on what change to make in the below code to accomplish that??Or do I have to make a different design approach for the models?
I have a `user`, `listing`, `conversation` and `message` model

**conversation.rb**

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, scope: :recipient_id

  scope :involving, -> (user) do
    where("conversations.sender_id = ? OR conversations.recipient_id = ?", user.id, user.id)
  end

  scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) do
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?)",
          sender_id, recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
end
```

**Message.rb**

```
 class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :conversation
      belongs_to :user

      validates_presence_of :content, :conversation_id, :user_id

      def message_time
        created_at.strftime("%v")
      end
    end


conversations_controller.rb

class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
           @conversations = Conversation.involving(current_user)
  end

  def create
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present?
      @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
      @conversation = Conversation.create(conversation_params)
    end

    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end

  private

  def conversation_params
    params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
  end
end
```

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_conversation

  def index
    if current_user == @conversation.sender || current_user == @conversation.recipient
      @other = current_user == @conversation.sender ? @conversation.recipient : @conversation.sender
      @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")
    else
      redirect_to conversations_path, alert: "You don't have permission to view this."
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
    @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")

    if @message.save
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end
  end

  private

  def set_conversation
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:content, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relations are off. A conversation where the sender and recipient are fixed is no good - in fact thats just a monolog!

Instead we need a real **many to many** relation. That means we need a third table to store the link between users and converstations

So lets start by generating a model:

```
rails g model UserConversation user:belongs_to conversation:belongs_to
```

This will generate a model and a migration for a join table which will link users and conversations. We should now also take care of the uniqueness requirement. Open up the migration:

```
class CreateUserConversations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_conversations do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :conversation, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    # Add this constraint
    add_index :user_conversations, [:user_id, :conversation_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

That constraint that ensures the uniqueness on the database level and protects against race conditions. We also want a validation on the software level.

```
class UserConversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
  
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :conversation_id
end
```

Now we setup the relations in User and Conversation so that they go through the join model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :conversations, through: user_conversations

  def has_joined?(conversation)
    conversations.where(id: conversation).exist?
  end
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :messages
  has_many :users, through: user_conversations

  def includes_user?(user)
    users.where(id: user).exist?
  end
end
```

This lets us do `@user.conversations` or `@conversation.users`. We don't need the hacky scopes.

This is an example of how you could possibly add a user to a conversation on the fly:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  # ...

  def create
    unless current_user.has_joined?(conversation)
      # @todo handle case where this fails
      @conversation.users << current_user
    end

    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params) do |m|
      # get the current user from the session or a token
      # using params is an open invitation for hacking
      m.user = current_user 
    end

    if @message.save
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ... 
end
```

But note that you still have quite a way to go and will likely need several different controllers to properly represent messages in different contexts:

```
/messages/:id => MessagesController
/users/:user_id/messages => Users::MessagesController
/conversations/:id/messages => Conversations::MessagesController
```

Comment: This is just a start on how to fix some of the issues in your app. This is a very common domain so you might want to scour github for open source apps with a messaging system and review how they have approached the problems involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate..This helps...Isn't it same as mentioning polymorphic to true?

Comment: No, polymorphic relations are where you have a relation and the type of the associated record is dynamic.  Like if you have an Image that can belong to a `Article` or `Slideshow`. This is a many to many relation through a join model. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: @max quick question that I'm having trouble finding an answer to: in this setup, how do you ensure that if one person deletes a thread that it doesn't delete their copy of the messages?

Comment: @geoboy I really haven't addressed that at all here and thats really a completely separate question.